# Angular errors with Linux

Tags: angularjs

```
 ./server.sh 
internal/modules/run_main.js:54
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/home/racal/JavaScript/pluralsight/AngularFundamentalsFiles/DemoApp/scripts/eventsController' imported from /home/racal/JavaScript/pluralsight/AngularFundamentalsFiles/DemoApp/scripts/web-server.js
    at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:272:11)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:652:10)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:695:13)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:97:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:243:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:41:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

and in web console

```
 angular.js:10413 GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/app/lib/app/data/event 404 (Not Found)
```

please help me
I wanted to change event data about an event object in javascript, a json-file

Comment: you are importing eventsController somewhere in your code?

Comment: yes , i imported in EventDetails.html

Comment: imported from /home/racal/JavaScript/pluralsight/AngularFundamentalsFiles/DemoApp/scripts/web-server.js
    at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:272:11)

Comment: give that statement?

Comment: ``` import express from 'express'
import path from 'path'
import events from './eventsController'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
var app = express()
var rootPath = path.normalize(path.join() + '/../')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.static(rootPath + '../app'))

app.get('/data/event/:id', events.get)
app.post('/data/event/:id', events.save)
app.listen(8100)
console.log('Listening on port 8100....')
```

Comment: 'use strict'

eventsApp.controller('EditEventController',
  function EditEventController ($scope) {
    $scope.event = {}
    $scope.cancelEvent = function() {
      window.location = './EventDetails.html'
    }
    $scope.saveEvent = function (event, newEventForm) {
      if (newEventForm.$valid) {
        if ($scope.event.name === 'Sami') {
          window.alert('Sa traiti' + $scope.event.name + '!!!!!') 
        }

        else {
          window.alert('Event' + $scope.event.name + 'Saved')
        }
      }
    }
  }
)